# When a function returns an object is a copy made?

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have the following statement

```
CGRect frame =  CGRectMake(0,0,200,150) ;
```

I wanted to know if a copy is made in this case. I just started with objectiveC and I only know when and how to make copies with pointers which is implementing the method

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone;
```

Comment: A copy of what? `frame` is a C struct. That has nothing whatever to do with `copyWithZone`, which is about copying _objects_. A C struct is not an object. Your question makes no sense. What are you actually trying to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not necessarily for the reason you might be thinking.

A `CGRect` is a C struct, not an Objective-C object. `CGRectMake` returns a *new* `CGRect`, and since it's not returning a pointer (it is returning a value), it's not pointing to an existing struct in memory, and you can safely assume it is a "copy", or a unique, discrete struct.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I come from a c++ background so I guess that  question sounded weird with objectiveC